# I wish I hadn't/haven't/hadn't had

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I'd like to know which expression (and why) should I use in this sentence:

> I wish I hadn't had Acrophobia.

This doesn't seem correct but is it just "hadn't", "wouldn't have" or "didn't have" instead of "hadn't had"? Or something completely different?

Thank you

Comment: Well it depends what you want to say. Do you have a fear of heights now? Did you have a fear then but not now? All of your possibilities could have meaning in the right context but they all mean different things.  Please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: I meant that I still have fear of heights but I'm not happy about it. Sorry, I should have been more specific. However, now I know the answer. Thank you very much for your time and also for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking back on an instance where fear of heights may have prevented you from moving forward with something that you now wish you had moved forward with **AND** your fear of heights has since vanished, then saying:

> I wish I hadn't had Acrophobia.

would make sense. Saying you wish you hadn't had it suggests that you no longer have it. It's tantamount to saying, "I wish I hadn't had Acrophobia at that time," which can either mean you experienced a unique moment of Acrophobia that you normally do not possess **OR** that your Acrophobia is no longer with you in the present but was in your past.

But if you had and still have that fear, then simply saying:

> I wish I didn't have Acrophobia.

would make more sense. Saying it this way you're still considering your fear as a current obstacle, but also still covering your bases for having it in your past. You're reminiscing (perhaps regretting a moment) by addressing the fear you still have.